# Changed URl in General Settings now Wordpress site doesnt work

Tags: php, fatal-error

My website URL was www.example.com/singer

I decided to get rid of "/singer" in the dashboard and ever since i have met with this error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp() in /data/15/3/113/145/3439634/user/3834081/htdocs/singer/wp-blog-header.php on line 14
```

I've tried multiple methods to fix but all with no luck.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Please, explain what you have done to get rid of "/singer". If you have moved Wordpress, [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) can help. If you have not move Wordpress, see [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Comment: I only did it because it gave me the option. Did not move any files at all.

Comment: change the site URL properly: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `wp-config.php`

```
 define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'www.amandabarise.com/singer' );
 define('WP_HOME', 'www.amandabarise.com/singer');
```

That should make the site work again, but try to correct the values, and [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Comment: I think hardcode the url of your site in the config file is really bad.

Comment: Did what you suggested, and it didn't work.

Comment: it seems that you have another problem.